# You [noun] you -what does it mean and when to use?

Tags: meaning, idioms, pronouns

In few occasions I've heard that actors and characters in tv add another 'you' when they are talking to somebody else resulting in an odd "you [insert something here] you" -sentence.

Example: Guy 1: "I finally did it!" Guy 2:"You sure did, you sly dog you!"

Questions that bother me:
**What is this sort of sentence/idiom/expression called and what is it for? Is it proper language or slang? What does it imply and why would you use it?**

Comment: It is colloquial spoken English, although little used these days. It is a form of emphasis and, in this case, used in grudging (or wry) admiration. I wouldn't try to use it unless you are very sure of yourself. I think that there should be a comma before the final *you*.

Comment: It's emphatic repetition, as in ***You** [are a] **sly dog, you** [are a sly dog]*, with many of the repeated elements "deleted". Or maybe not, since you can't exactly apply that rationale to ***He's a sly dog, him!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say that the correct expansion is ***You** [are a] **sly dog, you** [are].* Your second example is almost there: ***He's a sly dog, he is!***

Comment: @Mick : What I meant by my *maybe not* above was that we can't simply say the final element represents the surviving part of ***you** [are]* or ***you** [are a sly dog]* after deletion. That line works for ***you*** because the subject/object versions of the pronoun are identical. But not with ***he*** because you have to switch to ***him*** if you delete the final repeated verb ***is***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Mick So it's not a case of *you* appearing in Determiner function with *sly dog* appearing as the nominal then, a la *you bastard* or *we band of brothers*? And then that last *you* is definitely not a right dislocation, right?

Comment: @Araucaria, Mick: Me, I think OP's construction here is definitely not the same as *we band of brothers*. Granted, you probably wouldn't move the initial (object) pronoun to the *end* of that previous sentence, but I certainly have no problem with ***I'm the meanest motherf###er  in the valley, me!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're only taking into account the second *you* there. The *me* in your construction and the second *you* in the OP's is a right dislocation. The first is a pronoun in Det function as in *we band of brothers* or *you numpty* ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers .. or *us linguists* or *them bones*.

Comment: @Araucaria: *them bones?* Surely you mean ***dem bones*** *(dem bones, dem **dry** bones!).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @FumbleFingers, that repeating the personal pronoun is empathic repetition. It is only slang and should be omitted from formal writing; at present and for the near future. It implies that you are putting an emphasis on the fact that this person is a sly dog, and they probably beat you at something. It can be used to vent this feeling, and it is used by some people in speech to express this.

Comment: That answers most of my questions. Thank you very much. I should probably refrain from using it just to be sure. Out of curiosity: is 'you [noun] you' used more in UK or US english?

Comment: @Toteemi I don't really know, because I do not hear that much UK English, but I would guess it is more common in US English.